# Unable to add new dependencies gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I just released an app on playstore and there I just followed the steps given on developer.google.com to change the build.gradle file.

However, since then when I try to enter a new dependency I always get the following error:

> Error:(48, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.TakeoffAndroid:MaterialDialogBottomSheet:333ac64d71
>   Show in File
> Show in Project Structure dialog

This my gradle file for reference:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'dsfdsfdsfdsf'
        keyPassword 'fsdkjfdskjfkjdsf'
        storeFile file('C:/Users/Gaurav/AndroidStudioProjects/dsfdsfds.jks')
        storePassword 'kndfkjdsklfjsdk'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sdfdsfdsf.sdfdsfds"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
}

repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
// support libraries
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
// google play services location api
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
// making connection requests
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
// animation
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
compile 'com.github.TakeoffAndroid:MaterialDialogBottomSheet:333ac64d71'
}
```

I also tried with several other dependencies to see if anything wrong was with that dependency. However all fail the same way. Please help me figure out, what is wrong.

Comment: `com.github.TakeoffAndroid` is this on jcenter or something?

Comment: using it from android arsenal, I guess they keep a separate version. Please check under package: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2057

Comment: Maybe jitpack really does not have it. Did you check jit pack?

Comment: It is available https://jitpack.io/#TakeoffAndroid/MaterialDialogBottomSheet/333ac64d71

Comment: [Chandru](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3298272/chandru) is the author of takeoff android. You may directly try asking him meanwhile I will personally inform him.

Comment: thank you for that, however I think the problem is not with the repo or library. I think something is wrong with my environment or code.The same is happening with all new libraries

Comment: The problem has been fixed! I think it was a temporary issue with the repo provider. Thank you everyone for the insights!

Comment: @HarishSridharan Thanks for informing me. The problem is only with jitpack.

Comment: @JaredBurrows You are right jitpack in not available for my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MaterialDialogBottomSheet is not a library. Kindly remove the line from the gradle dependencies (i.e `compile'com.github.TakeoffAndroid:MaterialDialogBottomSheet:333ac64d71'`). The repo is just a custom implementation of dialog which can be used as BottomSheet. Please download the project from my github [link](https://github.com/TakeoffAndroid/MaterialDialogBottomSheet) and run the project straightaway in Android Studio. If you want to integrate BottomSheet in your application, just copy the codes from activity, layouts, styles (Dialog style theme), anim (Top to Bottom animation xml) from my project. It should work for sure. Further if you have any doubts and queries let me know. Thanks. Happy coding!.

Comment: Hi Chandru! thanks for the solution. Please take a look at the website: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2057 under packages. Please ask them to remove this. It may be misleading to the users. Btw, it was a temporary issue jitpack. I was using another library. I used yours to check if it is the library's fault of repo's fault. What a coincidence. :D Thanks for your help. I'll mark this as the answer in case users have the same bug while using MaterialDialogBottonSheet. :)

Comment: Ya sure. Thanks for your postings and bringing this issue. I will work on it to rectify.

Answer (score 2):

First you make sure that "com.github.TakeoffAndroid:MaterialDialogBottomSheet:333ac64d71" .jar/.aar available in your project, if not then try

```
1. Go to File->Project Structure
2. Click on "+" sign (insert new module), Select import jar/aar packages, provide the path of your jar.
3.then select your module name and go to dependency tab
4. click on "+" (Add) "module dependency"
5. click Apply and then ok
```